# How can I map a stored procedure to EF 6.1.1 Code First or later?

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework

I have been using the following code to execute a stored procedure in my C# controllers. db is my EF database context.

```
var sql = @"dbo.sp_add_test  @CreatedBy,
                             @CreatedDate,
                             @TestId,
                             @TestStatusId";   
List<SqlParameter> parameterList = new List<SqlParameter>();
parameterList.Add(new SqlParameter("@CreatedBy", Int32.Parse(User.Identity.GetUserId()) ));
parameterList.Add(new SqlParameter("@CreatedDate", DateTime.UtcNow));
parameterList.Add(new SqlParameter("@TestId", testId));
parameterList.Add(new SqlParameter("@TestStatusId", 3));
SqlParameter[] parameters = parameterList.ToArray();


var test = await db.Database.SqlQuery<Test>(sql, parameters).FirstOrDefaultAsync();
```

I've had suggestions "why don't you map your SP in the EF context?"  However when I did research on this I found it very unclear as to how to do this.  First of all I saw there's a nuget package out there:

http://www.nuget.org/packages/EntityFramework.CodeFirstStoreFunctions/

But I am not clear. Is this the only way to do it or has something changed. I see posts on the internet and SO but it appears that things are changing very recently so I think these may now be out of date.

Can someone tell me how it's now done for EF 6.1.1. Please note I am looking for the official way to do this using only Microsoft tools. Also note I am using Code First so I cannot use the edmx mapper etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Officially it's not supported. You can use an add-on, written by one of the EF team members, as linked in the post, but that's about it.

You can also use tooling to make this work (like LLBLGen Pro, which can create the proc call mappings in the DbContext class for you: http://www.llblgen.com/documentation/4.2/Entity%20Framework/hh_goto.htm#V56/CodeFirstSupport.htm), but you're not allowed to do so, as you're looking for official tools only. I'd say: the official tools suck in many areas with respect to EF, so if you're only looking for official tooling for this and other things related to EF, you're in for a hell (literaly) of a ride ;)

Comment: this contectually incorrect, Fluent API has the ability and functionality to execute SProcs and Functions.  It can be done directly off the DBContext or through ModelBuilder.

Answer (score 1):

This appears to be an insert function, which is supported natively by Entity Framework 6.1.  Information on how this works is in the [Codeplex Documentation](https://entityframework.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Code%20First%20Insert/Update/Delete%20Stored%20Procedure%20Mapping).

Essentially, you use the fluent API to map your entity to the stored procedure rather than the default insert/update/delete queries.  As an example:

```
modelBuilder
    .Entity<Test>()
    .MapToStoredProcedures (s =>
        s.Insert(i => i.HasName("sp_add_test")
            .Parameter(t => t.CreatedBy, "CreatedBy")
            .Parameter(t => t.CreatedDate, "CreatedDate")
            .Parameter(t => t.TestId, "TestId")
            .Parameter(t => t.TestStatusId, "TestStatusId")));
```

as a note:

**Limitations**

- Stored procedure mapping can currently only be done with the Fluent API. In the future we may look at an attribute based (Data Annotation) alternative.
- You cannot use a mixture of stored procedures and direct table access for a given entity (or entity hierarchy). The insert, update and delete operations must all use direct table access or stored procedures.

Comment: That's a proc mapped for an entity persistence action, not a general proc which e.g. could return a resultset.

Comment: true, I just inferred that this was probably an insert proc from the name and the parameter list. It's not likely that you are searching the database using a `CreatedDate` as `DateTime.Now`, but the question itself wasn't entirely clear.

Answer (score 0):

These are Extensions but can be easily migrated to methods off the main class that inherits form the DBContext class.

Here are 3 general signatures all my SProcs/Function methods consist of.

```
    public static IEnumerable<T> ExecuteSProc<T> ( this DbContext ctx , string schema , string sproc , params SqlParameter[] para ) {
        return ctx.Database.SqlQuery<T>( "Execute " + schema + "." + sproc , para ).ToArray();
    }
    public static T ExecuteSProcSingle<T> ( this DbContext ctx , string schema , string sproc , params SqlParameter[] para ) {
        return ctx.Database.SqlQuery<T>( "Execute " + schema + "." + sproc , para ).SingleOrDefault();
    }

    public static int ExecuteSProc ( this DbContext ctx , string schema , string sproc , params SqlParameter[] para ) {
        return ctx.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand( "Execute " + schema + "." + sproc , para );
    }
```

I will periodically post little quirks that I culminated over several posts into a singularly built concept of implementation here: http://theithobbit.blogspot.com/

The big picture, you ask:

```
public static class DbContextExtension {
    public static IEnumerable<T> ExecuteSProc<T> ( this DbContext ctx , string schema , string sproc , params SqlParameter[] para ) {
        return ctx.Database.SqlQuery<T>( "Execute " + schema + "." + sproc , para ).ToArray();
    }
    public static T ExecuteSProcSingle<T> ( this DbContext ctx , string schema , string sproc , params SqlParameter[] para ) {
        return ctx.Database.SqlQuery<T>( "Execute " + schema + "." + sproc , para ).SingleOrDefault();
    }

    public static int ExecuteSProc ( this DbContext ctx , string schema , string sproc , params SqlParameter[] para ) {
        return ctx.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand( "Execute " + schema + "." + sproc , para );
    }
}
```